# Add class to HTML by hash in .Net and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

```
<nav>
    <ul class="reslist-page pagination">
        @for (int i = 1; i < Model.PageCount - 1; i++)
        {
            <li><a href="@Url.Action()?page=@i">@i</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
</nav>
```

HTML output:

```
   <nav>
        <ul class="reslist-page pagination">
                <li><a href="?page=1">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="?page=2">2</a></li>
        </ul>
   </nav>
```

When I go to my website www.website.com, `page=1` is active. If click any pagination button go to abot that page. 
And I want `active` class about li. How can I fix this?

Comment: not able to understand question clearly???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but maybe it will work.

```
<nav>
        <ul class="reslist-page pagination">
            @if (@Model.PageCount > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= Model.PageCount; i++)
                {
                    if (i == @Model.PageIndex)
                    {
                        <li class="active"><a href="@Url.Action()?page=@i">@i</a></li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action()?page=@i">@i</a></li>
                    }
                }
            }
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action()?page=@i" class="@(Request["page"] == i.ToString() ? "selected" : "")">>@i</a></li>
```

I haven't tried this, but hopefully that is the gist of what you are trying to do.

Alternatively:

```
@for (int i = 1; i < Model.PageCount - 1; i++)
    {
        string pageNo = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["page"]) ? "1" : Request["page"];

        <li class="@(pageNo == i.ToString() ? "active" : "")"><a href="@Url.Action()?page=@i">@i</a></li>
    }
```

This should account for when you first access the page and the "page" value is missing.

Comment: The class needs to be moved from the "a" to the "li" (just noticed in the original question). If the querystring contains page then the class should become "selected" (or "active"). If page is blank (which it will be first time) then it will not match i.